# How to write this windowing query in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

I have some tables to store flying data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[wings]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Manufacturer] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Size] [decimal](3, 1) NULL,
    [hoursWhenBought] [tinyint] NULL,
    [purchaseDate] [date] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__wings__3214EC07E42B45BC] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[wingServiceHistory]
(
    [wingId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [servicedBy] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [comments] [varchar](200) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_wingServiceHistory] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([wingId] ASC, [date] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[flights]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [TakeOffTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [LandingTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [WingId] [int] NULL
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-Date] 
ON [dbo].[flights] ([Date] ASC)

-- Sample data
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (1, CAST(N'2019-09-02' AS Date), CAST(N'10:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'12:00:00' AS Time), 3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (2, CAST(N'2019-09-03' AS Date), CAST(N'09:30:00' AS Time), CAST(N'12:30:00' AS Time), 3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (3, CAST(N'2020-05-05' AS Date), CAST(N'07:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'08:45:00' AS Time), 3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (4, CAST(N'2020-09-28' AS Date), CAST(N'13:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'15:00:00' AS Time), 3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (5, CAST(N'2021-01-03' AS Date), CAST(N'17:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'19:00:00' AS Time), 8)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (6, CAST(N'2021-01-05' AS Date), CAST(N'15:30:00' AS Time), CAST(N'17:00:00' AS Time), 8)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (7, CAST(N'2021-08-25' AS Date), CAST(N'06:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'08:00:00' AS Time), 8)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (8, CAST(N'2021-08-26' AS Date), CAST(N'07:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'09:30:00' AS Time), 3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (9, CAST(N'2021-09-01' AS Date), CAST(N'06:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'07:00:00' AS Time), 8)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (10, CAST(N'2022-08-10' AS Date), CAST(N'07:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'09:00:00' AS Time), 8)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (11, CAST(N'2022-10-17' AS Date), CAST(N'15:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'17:00:00' AS Time), 13)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (12, CAST(N'2022-10-19' AS Date), CAST(N'16:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'18:00:00' AS Time), 8)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[flights] ([Id], [Date], [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime], [WingId]) 
VALUES (13, CAST(N'2022-12-21' AS Date), CAST(N'13:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'15:30:00' AS Time), 13)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[wings] ([Id], [Manufacturer], [Model], [Size], [hoursWhenBought], [purchaseDate]) 
VALUES (2, N'Dudek', N'Synthesis LT', CAST(31.0 AS Decimal(3, 1)), 45, CAST(N'2017-11-04' AS Date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[wings] ([Id], [Manufacturer], [Model], [Size], [hoursWhenBought], [purchaseDate]) 
VALUES (3, N'Dudek', N'Universal 1.1', CAST(28.0 AS Decimal(3, 1)), 0, CAST(N'2019-08-23' AS Date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[wings] ([Id], [Manufacturer], [Model], [Size], [hoursWhenBought], [purchaseDate]) 
VALUES (8, N'Dudek', N'Nucleon XX', CAST(24.0 AS Decimal(3, 1)), 150, CAST(N'2021-01-02' AS Date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[wings] ([Id], [Manufacturer], [Model], [Size], [hoursWhenBought], [purchaseDate]) 
VALUES (13, N'Dudek', N'Hadron 3', CAST(20.0 AS Decimal(3, 1)), 3, CAST(N'2022-10-16' AS Date))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[wingServiceHistory] ([wingId], [date], [servicedBy], [comments]) 
VALUES (3, CAST(N'2020-09-21' AS Date), N'Joe Blogs', N'full trim service')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[wingServiceHistory] ([wingId], [date], [servicedBy], [comments]) 
VALUES (8, CAST(N'2021-08-24' AS Date), N'Joe Blogs', N'full trim service')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[wingServiceHistory] ([wingId], [date], [servicedBy], [comments]) 
VALUES (8, CAST(N'2022-08-03' AS Date), N'Joe Blogs', N'full trim service')
```

This query returns the flight duration and cumulative hours for all wings across all flights:

```sql
SELECT
    Id,
    [Date],
    CAST(DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime]), 0) AS time) AS Duration,
    CAST ((SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, [TakeOffTime], [LandingTime])) OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) / 60.0) AS DECIMAL(10, 1)) AS CumulativeHours
FROM  
    flights
```

I need a query that, for each flight in the `flights` table, ordered by `flights.Id`, the cumulative hours for each `wingId` since the last service date from `wingServiceHistory` or since the purchase date in `wings` whichever is sooner.

Or, in English, for every flight, how many hours has this wing been flown since the last service, or the number of hours since it was purchased including the hours when bought.

Results set desired is every column in the `flights` table plus `duration`, `cumulativeHours`, `cumulativeHoursSinceService`

I would expect results to look like

| Id | Date | TakeOffTime | LandingTime | WingId | duration (HH:MM) | cumulativeHours | cumulativeHoursSinceService |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-09-02 | 10:00 | 12:00 | 3 | 02:00 | 2.0 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 2019-09-03 | 09:30 | 12:30 | 3 | 03:00 | 5.0 | 5.0 |
| 3 | 2020-05-05 | 07:00 | 08:45 | 3 | 01:45 | 6.75 | 1.75 |
| 4 | 2020-09-28 | 13:00 | 15:00 | 3 | 02:00 | 8.75 | 2.0 |
| 5 | 2021-01-03 | 17:00 | 19:00 | 8 | 02:00 | 10.75 | 152.0 |
| 6 | 2021-01-05 | 15:30 | 17:00 | 8 | 01:30 | 12.25 | 153.5 |
| 7 | 2021-08-25 | 06:00 | 08:00 | 8 | 02:00 | 14.25 | 2.0 |
| 8 | 2021-08-26 | 07:00 | 09:30 | 3 | 02:30 | 16.75 | 4.75 |
| 9 | 2021-09-01 | 06:00 | 07:00 | 8 | 01:00 | 17.75 | 3.0 |
| 10 | 2022-08-10 | 07:00 | 09:00 | 8 | 02:00 | 19.75 | 2.0 |
| 11 | 2022-10-17 | 15:00 | 17:00 | 13 | 02:00 | 21.75 | 5.0 |
| 12 | 2022-10-19 | 16:00 | 18:00 | 8 | 02:00 | 23.75 | 4.0 |
| 13 | 2022-12-21 | 13:00 | 15:30 | 13 | 02:30 | 26.25 | 7.5 |

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky all of this was already present.

Comment: Correct. I missed the *sample data population*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach for this is a couple of windowed functions to grab what you need. In this case you're also looking for a specific correlated row in the service history, so I opted for an outer apply for that.

```
SELECT f.Id, f.Date, f.TakeOffTime, f.LandingTime, w.id AS WingID, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TakeOffTime,LandingTime),'00:00:00') AS TIME) AS Duration,
CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TakeOffTime,LandingTime)) OVER (ORDER BY f.id)/60.0 AS DECIMAL(4,2)) AS CumulativeHours,
CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TakeOffTime,LandingTime)) OVER (PARTITION BY w.id, wsh.date ORDER BY f.id)/60.0 AS DECIMAL(4,2))+CASE WHEN wsh.date IS NULL THEN hoursWhenBought ELSE 0 END AS CumulativeHoursSinceService 
  FROM @flights f
    INNER JOIN @wings w
      ON f.WingId = w.Id
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @wingServiceHistory wsh WHERE wingid = w.id and date <= f.Date ORDER BY date) wsh
 ORDER BY f.id
```

| Id | Date | TakeOffTime | LandingTime | WingID | Duration | CumulativeHours | CumulativeHoursSinceService |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-09-02 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 12:00:00.0000000 | 3 | 02:00:00.0000000 | 2.00 | 2.00 |
| 2 | 2019-09-03 | 09:30:00.0000000 | 12:30:00.0000000 | 3 | 03:00:00.0000000 | 5.00 | 5.00 |
| 3 | 2020-05-05 | 07:00:00.0000000 | 08:45:00.0000000 | 3 | 01:45:00.0000000 | 6.75 | 6.75 |
| 4 | 2020-09-28 | 13:00:00.0000000 | 15:00:00.0000000 | 3 | 02:00:00.0000000 | 8.75 | 2.00 |
| 5 | 2021-01-03 | 17:00:00.0000000 | 19:00:00.0000000 | 8 | 02:00:00.0000000 | 10.75 | 152.00 |
| 6 | 2021-01-05 | 15:30:00.0000000 | 17:00:00.0000000 | 8 | 01:30:00.0000000 | 12.25 | 153.50 |
| 7 | 2021-08-25 | 06:00:00.0000000 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 8 | 02:00:00.0000000 | 14.25 | 2.00 |
| 8 | 2021-08-26 | 07:00:00.0000000 | 09:30:00.0000000 | 3 | 02:30:00.0000000 | 16.75 | 4.50 |
| 9 | 2021-09-01 | 06:00:00.0000000 | 07:00:00.0000000 | 8 | 01:00:00.0000000 | 17.75 | 3.00 |
| 10 | 2022-08-10 | 07:00:00.0000000 | 09:00:00.0000000 | 8 | 02:00:00.0000000 | 19.75 | 5.00 |
| 11 | 2022-10-17 | 15:00:00.0000000 | 17:00:00.0000000 | 13 | 02:00:00.0000000 | 21.75 | 5.00 |
| 12 | 2022-10-19 | 16:00:00.0000000 | 18:00:00.0000000 | 8 | 02:00:00.0000000 | 23.75 | 7.00 |
| 13 | 2022-12-21 | 13:00:00.0000000 | 15:30:00.0000000 | 13 | 02:30:00.0000000 | 26.25 | 7.50 |

Windowed functions allow you to define the window they use by specifying them in the OVER clause:

PARTITION BY - group by these things
ORDER BY - in this order

With the SUM for the cumulative hours we're asking for the running total, ordered by flight id.

With the SUM for the hours since service we're again asking for the running total, but this time grouped by the wing id and the service date (so it starts over for each new one) and ordered by flight id.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example. I think, it is important to calculate `resource used after last service` and `total used resource` for every WingId. So, query result differs from desired.
Upd1:`hoursWhenBought` are considered not serviced (condition1 added to query).

```
with data as(
select WingId,'flight' EventType,date eventDate,TakeOffTime,LandingTime,id
  ,(datediff(mi,TakeOffTime,LandingTime)
    +case when TakeOffTime>LandingTime then 1440 else 0 end)/60.0  workHours
from flights
union all
select Id as WingId,'purchase' EventType,purchaseDate as eventDate,null,null,0
  ,hoursWhenBought  workHours
from wings
union all
select WingId,'Service' EventType,date eventDate,null,null,0
  ,0 workHours
from wingServiceHistory
)
,LifeCicles as(
select * 
  ,sum(case when eventType='purchase' or eventType='service' then 1 else 0 end)
     over(partition by wingId order by eventDate) cicleN
from data
)
select WingId,EventType,eventDate,TakeOffTime TOff,LandingTime LT,workHours wHours,cicleN
  ,sum(workHours)over(partition by wingId order by eventDate) cumHours
  ,sum(case when eventType='flight' 
               or eventType='purchase'  -- added condition1
           then workHours else 0 end)
      over(partition by wingId,cicleN order by eventDate) cumService
  , id
  ,sum(case when eventType='flight' then workHours else 0 end)
           over(order by eventDate) totHours  -- total for all flights
from LifeCicles
order by wingId,eventDate,id
```

Result(draft). Here wHours -duration or hoursWhenBought. Column names shorted for clearity.

| WingId | EventT. | eventDate | TOff | LandT | wHours | cicleN | cumTotal | cumService | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | purchase | 2017-11-04 | null | null | 45.00 | 1 | 45.00 | 45.00 | 0 |
| 3 | purchase | 2019-08-23 | null | null | 0.000 | 1 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 3 | flight | 2019-09-02 | 10:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 2.000 | 1 | 2.00 | 2.00 | 1 |
| 3 | flight | 2019-09-03 | 09:30:00 | 12:30:00 | 3.000 | 1 | 5.00 | 5.00 | 2 |
| 3 | flight | 2020-05-05 | 07:00:00 | 08:45:00 | 1.750 | 1 | 6.75 | 6.75 | 3 |
| 3 | Service | 2020-09-21 | null | null | 0.000 | 2 | 6.75 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 3 | flight | 2020-09-28 | 13:00:00 | 15:00:00 | 2.000 | 2 | 8.75 | 2.00 | 4 |
| 3 | flight | 2021-08-26 | 07:00:00 | 09:30:00 | 2.500 | 2 | 11.25 | 4.50 | 8 |
| 8 | purchase | 2021-01-02 | null | null | 150.000 | 1 | 150.00 | 150.00 | 0 |
| 8 | flight | 2021-01-03 | 17:00:00 | 19:00:00 | 2.000 | 1 | 152.00 | 152.00 | 5 |
| 8 | flight | 2021-01-05 | 15:30:00 | 17:00:00 | 1.500 | 1 | 153.50 | 153.50 | 6 |
| 8 | Service | 2021-08-24 | null | null | 0.000 | 2 | 153.50 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 8 | flight | 2021-08-25 | 06:00:00 | 08:00:00 | 2.000 | 2 | 155.50 | 2.00 | 7 |
| 8 | flight | 2021-09-01 | 06:00:00 | 07:00:00 | 1.000 | 2 | 156.50 | 3.00 | 9 |
| 8 | Service | 2022-08-03 | null | null | 0.000 | 3 | 156.50 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 8 | flight | 2022-08-10 | 07:00:00 | 09:00:00 | 2.000 | 3 | 158.50 | 2.00 | 10 |
| 8 | flight | 2022-10-19 | 16:00:00 | 18:00:00 | 2.000 | 3 | 160.50 | 4.00 | 12 |
| 13 | purchase | 2022-10-16 | null | null | 3.000 | 1 | 3.00 | 3.00 | 0 |
| 13 | flight | 2022-10-17 | 15:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 2.000 | 1 | 5.00 | 5.00 | 11 |
| 13 | flight | 2022-12-21 | 13:00:00 | 15:30:00 | 2.500 | 1 | 7.50 | 7.50 | 13 |

[Example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WzvqhDPI)